# Yii2 : Dependent Dropdown List

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to use dependent dropdown list in yii2-advanced app, using 2 models - `BusinessMainCategories(bmc_id, bmc_name) & BusinessSubCategories(bsc_id, bsc_name, bmc_id)`. I've to use the dropdown list on the page located in frontend. 
I've tried the following but it displays all the sub categories in db every time.

My view code is as -

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
    <?php
        $dataBMC = ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\BusinessMainCategories::find()->asArray()->all(), 'bmc_id', 'bmc_name');
        echo $form->field($model, 'bmc_id')->dropDownList($dataBMC, 
         ['prompt'=>'Choose a Main Category',
            'style'=>'width:75%',
          'onchange'=>'
            $.post("index.php?r=business-sub-categories/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), 
                function(data) {
              $("select#business_sub_categories-bsc_id" ).html( data );
            });
        ']); 
        echo "<br>";
        $dataBSC = ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\BusinessSubCategories::find()->asArray()->all(), 'bsc_id', 'bsc_name');
        echo $form->field($model, 'bmc_id')
            ->dropDownList(
                $dataBSC,           
                ['prompt'=>'Choose a Sub Category',
                'style'=>'width:75%',
                'id'=>'bmc_id']
            );
    ?>
    <div class="form-group"><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Submit" class='btn btn-success'>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I'm confused with where should I write the code for list function? I'm writing it in backend\controllers\BusinessSubCategoriesController as follows -

```
public function actionLists($id)
{
    $countBSCategories = BusinessSubCategories::find()->where(['bmc_id' => $id])->count();
    $businessSubCategories = BusinessSubCategories::find()->where(['bmc_id' => $id])->all();
    if ($countBSCategories > 0) {
        foreach ($businessSubCategories as $businessSubCategory) {
            echo "<option value='" . $businessSubCategory->bsc_id . "'>" . $businessSubCategory->bsc_name . "</option>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<option> - </option>";
    }
}
```

I think the function is not getting 'bmc_id' properly. Please tell me a solution to make it dependent by correcting my mistakes...

Comment: Use [getInputId()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#getInputId%28%29-detail) for accurate id.

Comment: what is wrong with my view? I'm not able to identify it.

Comment: I don't know. but i can suggest you slightly different approach. what i am using. If you want to?

Comment: yeah why not, please!

Comment: ok. checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The Same Scenario-***

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(ItemCategory::find()->all(),'id','ic_code'),
    ['prompt'=>'Select Category',
    'onchange' => '
    $.post("index.php?r=receiving-order-details/lists&id=' . '"+$(this).val(),function(data){
      $("select#receivingorderdetails-sub_category_id").html(data);
    });']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'sub_category_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(ItemSubCategory::find()->all(),'id','isc_code'),['prompt'=>'Select Sub Category']) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `get` method and you are using same field for both Dropdown. so, change it.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'bmc_id')->dropDownList($dataBMC, 
                     ['prompt'=>'Choose a Main Category',
                        'style'=>'width:75%',
                      'onchange'=>'
          $.get( "'.Url::toRoute('business-sub-categories/lists').'", { id: $(this).val() })
         .done(function( data ) { $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'attribute').'" ).html( data ); } );'
]);
```

Comment: if I use the following, it displays sub categories correctly for that specific id -                         
`$dataBSC = ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\BusinessSubCategories::find()->where(['bmc_id'=>'1'])->all(), 'bsc_id', 'bsc_name');`
        That is, it works for a specific id given by us, but not taking id from parent dropdown.

Comment: My both models are in different objects, MainCategories is in model & SubCategories is in model4. Is it okay ? If not, I tried it using model4 only `(BusinessSubCategories(bsc_id, bsc_name, bmc_id)` , but though it doesn't work.

Comment: @TusharWalzade.  It doesn't matter ,we need only id of that attribute.

Comment: `<?= $form->field($model4, 'bmc_id')->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\BusinessMainCategories::find()->all(), 'bmc_id', 'bmc_name'), 
                    [
                        'prompt' => 'Select Main Category',
                        'onchange' =>'
                            $.post("index.php?r=business-sub-categories/lists' . '",{ id: $(this).val() })
                                .done(function(data){
                               $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model4, 'bsc_id').'" ).html(data);
                            });']);
                ?>`

Comment: `<?= $form->field($model4, 'bsc_id')->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\BusinessSubCategories::find()->all(), 'bsc_id', 'bsc_name'),           
                    [
                        'prompt' => 'Select Sub Category',
                    ]);
                ?>` Please review this once again

Comment: @TusharWalzade.  come here: [Yii chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99406/yii-warriors)